# Tokio's io::split with Cursor<Vec<u8>> won't get the full written data

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

while doing some tests with tokio, I noticed that when using `tokio::io::split` to have the writer and reader to be sent into different tasks, the reader part never waits for the writer to be closed nor for any write when the writing part is done in another task.
I tried finding on the documentation but, nothing that would explain the reason for this.
Did I miss something there?

This is a minimal code to reproduce that.

```
use std::io::Cursor;

use tokio::io::{self, AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};
use tokio::spawn;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let a = Cursor::new(vec![]);
    let (mut read, mut write) = io::split(a);

    spawn(async move {
        for i in 0..10 {
            write.write_all(&[i]).await.unwrap();
        }
    });

    let mut output = vec![];

    let written = read.read_buf(&mut output).await.unwrap();
    assert_eq!(written, 10);
}
```

Which can be executed from [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e1f41ad6f64e784b01b87319c90df053).

The output on playground is the following:

```
Execution
Format
Share
Close
Standard Error
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.60s
     Running `target/debug/playground`
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `0`,
 right: `10`', src/main.rs:20:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Standard Output
```

It just returns 0 instead of ten.
I'd imagine that it it sbecause the waker for `Cursor<Vec<_>>` would make sense to be always ready because there is no IO (assumption here) being done, unless you are piping data from somewhere else into the cursor.
I also tried `yield_now`, or `sleep` but, it never gets any data written to it.
I also made sure that the writer gets moved so on its drop it could flush and remaining data and close any handle it could have.

In a normal cursor I'd have to seek it to position 0 but, woudn't that defeat the purpose of split?

*UPDATE*

Here is [the result and where it is being used](https://github.com/jaysonsantos/transcribot/blob/ee9c584993ceaf5cc5a8d84ceeedcdc5a3056882/src/telegram.rs#L30-L38) so the functions can use AsyncRead and AsyncWrite.

Comment: [Even if you don't spawn task it doesn't work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3151a5b36ff124a0af1b98f12ef45ad8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an intended use-case. Tokio's `io::split` is primarily as a convenience for things like network streams (TCP, unix sockets, etc.) that have fully independent reading and writing streams. It is not intended for things like files and `Cursor`s whose reading and writing streams are not independent.

The problem you observe with `Cursor` is because it has only a single "position" that reads come from and writes write to. You *could* seek to zero for every read, but since that seek step is distinct from the read step, a write could happen in the middle and cause you to miss and/or misinterpret data.

If you want to share data between threads, why not a simple [channel](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html) or a [duplex](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/fn.duplex.html) stream?

Comment: Of course, you can write your own `Cursor` that keeps the write and read position independent.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I went that way because when I saw that there is an implementation of the trait for cursor of vec, I thought that there would be something channel based being done. My usage there is because I have two functions that I want to minimize memory usage and still make them concurrently and the first one is ffmpeg decoding a file from stdin to stdout and the second function using the data from stdin and spitting to stdout, effectively making a pipe. I guess I'll make a bounded channel of bytes chunks in the end.

Answer (score 2):

You have a conceptual misunderstanding about `Cursor`.

What you're thinking of is something like a pipe — throw in data on onse side, have it come out on the other. (tokio doesn't seem to have a pipe, only [two pipes bundled together](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/struct.DuplexStream.html). [This crate](https://docs.rs/tokio-pipe/latest/tokio_pipe/) seems to have a pipe.) Cursor isn't that, it's just a pointer into an array or vec, and both reading and writing will advance this same pointer. Hence, if you try to call read after write, you'll try to read from behind the end of what you just wrote.

It's difficult to play around with this in asynchronous code, especially since after `split`, you lose access to the underlying cursor. Try this code first, especially what happens without the `rewind`.

```rust
use std::io::{Cursor, Read, Write, Seek};

fn main() {
    let mut a = Cursor::new(vec![]);

    for i in 0..10 {
        a.write_all(&[i]).unwrap();
    }

    a.rewind().unwrap();

    let mut output = vec![42; 11];
    let written = a.read(&mut output).unwrap();
    dbg!((written, output));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8da16048eae77c3e40a53ccaa3d4ffe4)

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the answer. I get that and the usage of cursor, I when that route because I saw the trait being implemented and tried to use as an opportunity to manually create channels and kept my functions to use input and output parameters that are AsyncRead and AsyncWrite

Comment: From the looks of it, the duplex stream probably would work as my intention is to pipe many functions which are spawning processes and making use of their pipes in order to run concurrently

Comment: @JaysonReis Normally, that's more a usecase for `mpsc::channel`. since the receiver typically requires some kind of message semantics, and you'd end up having to extract that from the received bytes.